# Is it possible to configure s3proxy to respond on different url than {host}:{port}?

Tags: amazon-s3, s3proxy

I would like to make s3proxy to respond on url like {host}:{port}/s3 instead of just {host}:{port}. Is it possble to reconfigure default endpoint somehow?

I tried to set property like so s3proxy.endpoint={host}:{port}/s3 however I got en error:
endpoint path must be empty, was: /s3.
I also tried to set JCLOUDS_ENDPOINT to /s3 - no luck as well.

My properties file looks like so:

```
s3proxy.authorization=none
s3proxy.endpoint=http://127.0.0.1:80/s3.
jclouds.provider=filesystem
jclouds.filesystem.basedir=D:/devtools/s3proxy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the tool was really kind to point me to property which should be set to achieve wanted behavior, namely it is **s3proxy.service-path** which may be set like so:

```
s3proxy.service-path=/s3
```

I tested and it worked just OK.